# Issue in calling JpaRepository().save() method from multiple nodes Springboot

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have two nodes which are using same DB node. I am calling **JpaRepository().save()** method on the same row in a table from these two nodes(in the two calls time difference was around 10 seconds)but the changes of the last call were not reflected.

Are JpaRepository().save() calls on an entity row executed sequentially? If it is the case why the update of the last call was not reflected in the DB.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `JpaRepository().saveAndFlush()` or just `JpaRepository().flush()`after you called `JpaRepository().save()`?

Comment: I called JpaRepository().save() only